# I used rel="canonical" and hreflang="x-default", but global site is missing and receiving "no return tags" error

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, multilingual, hreflang, canonical-url

Here is a sample of the code

```
<link rel="canonical " href="http://www.kaspersky.com/anti-virus-trial" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-home-trials/anti-virus" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.kaspersky.co.in/anti-virus-trial" hreflang="en-in" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.kaspersky.com/anti-virus-trial" hreflang="x-default" />"
```

The hreflang tags are on all these URLs yet Google hasn't pick up the global site yet and found errors with US and India site with "no return tags". Is there something wrong with this coding on the Global version of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The hreflang tags are on all these URLs yet Google hasn't pick up the global site

Assuming that you're intending the last link to be the "global site", since you indicated that to be [default](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077) page with `hreflang="x-default"`, which `doesn't target any specific language or locale`,  then it's not necessary to specify the *canonical* link on each language specific page, as detailed in the example provided [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077) by Google:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en-gb.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us" href="http://en-us.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.example.com/seite.html" />
```

As stated there: `This markup tells Google's algorithm to consider all of these pages as alternate versions of each other`, so you wouldn't need to be concerned with duplicate content issues.

> ...and found errors with US and India site with "no return tags"

It appears you're referencing errors received under the [International Targeting](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n) feature in Google Webmaster Tools. As indicated in [this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/troubleshooting-hreflang-annotations-in.html) Webmaster Tools Blog, this allows you to identify one of the most common issues with *hreflang* annotations, *missing return links*:

> annotations must be confirmed from the pages
>   they are pointing to. If page A links to page B, page B must link back
>   to page A, otherwise the annotations may not be interpreted correctly.
>   For each error of this kind we report where and when we detected them,
>   as well as where the return link is expected to be.

So if you received errors for the US and Indian pages, the Googlebot is likely not able to identify the link back to the originating page. Having a look at the source code for your US and Indian pages, I see in each, respectively:

```
US:
<link rel="canonical" href="http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-home-trials/anti-virus" hreflang="en-us" />

India:
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.kaspersky.co.in/anti-virus-trial" hreflang="en-in" />
```

This is essentially telling the Googlebot that the canonical page is the *same* as the current page, since the URLs in these links just point to the same page location they're found on (i.e., to itself).

I suggest following the above example in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077), and do not include the canonical links pointing to the same page as itself.