# hreflang and no return tags with canonicals

Tags: canonical-url, hreflang

my question is in direct response to the following question...

[Canonical vs HREFLANG](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76667/i-used-rel-canonical-and-hreflang-x-default-but-global-site-is-missing-and)

I am in a similar situation. **However** we are using canonicals in each country to handle duplicated content caused by query parameters rather than duplicated international content. If we remove all the canonicals then we are at risk of having lots of duplicated content within a countries sub-folder. How do we overcome this issue?

Comment: Not sure why you'd be removing the canonical's. I don't see any reason why you couldn't use canonicals AND hreflang at the same time. You'd just want to be sure that the hreflang alternates point to the same  canonical "alternate" (without query parameters).